# Is it possible to execute a command-line application as a child thread?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, process

**NOTE:** Not asking about starting external processes, or a monitoring thread.

Is it possible, given a `byte[]` that represents a command-line .exe application, to execute it **within my process, as a thread**? (Given that the processor architecture between this application and mine is the same.)

If the user opens Task Manager, they should not see or have the opportunity to kill the "child process" without also killing off the parent application (among other things that makes this approach the best, in theory).

I'm thinking some way of dynamically importing the .exe as a reference and calling `main(args)`, but not sure how quickly this would fall apart since the application wouldn't necessarily have a Console context to deal with.

This seems to be similar to how Windows Service hosts behave, but have not seen it done in the managed world...

Comment: Is it possible, yes.  Should you do it, probably not.  With unsafe code you can always write out the bytes and then move the execution pointer to that code, but it's almost certainly a better idea to just write the bytes out to a file and execute the file, for security reasons.

Comment: Highly unlikely. The "child process" may have numerous assumptions about running in its own process to begin with.

Comment: @Brandon What is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: @xxbbcc can't disclose specific app, but have a "sensitive" process (same exe file, non-arbitrary) that needs to hide under its parent, and also cause the main app to crash if it crashes as well.

Comment: @Brandon That doesn't say much. If you control source to both processes, why not just implement the two as a single process? If you're trying to implement some kind of licensing scheme, it's almost guaranteed that you're on the wrong track.

Comment: @xxbbcc unfortunately don't control source on the cmd-line .exe side. I know, it's an architectural nightmare but, reasons...

Comment: @Brandon So what makes it sensitive? What prevents the user from running the cmdline .exe on its own? What prevents the user from just looking at the decompiled source of the .exe? (Assuming it's a managed .exe) Your question sounds like an X/Y problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @xxbbcc someone could certainly decompile it, extract the byte array from resources, save it to an .exe and run it and get params from the decompiled source. But the point of this req is not to make that impossible, but prevent the .exe from ever showing up in the system as more than a thread. I get the X/Y feeling...

Comment: @Brandon I get it :). I'm asking why is it necessary to prevent the user from doing so? It seems like you're generating an extra-hard problem for the sake of having a problem. It also sounds like licensing and/or copyright protection in which case it's guaranteed to be wrong track. Not trying to beat you over the head over and over about it, just trying to understand your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm thinking some way of dynamically importing the .exe as a reference
>   and calling main(args), but not sure how quickly this would fall apart
>   since the application wouldn't necessarily have a Console context to
>   deal with.

This is possible although executing an **arbitrary** exe may prove to be difficult.

**Cooperative**

It can be done in a cooperative manner by e.g. loading it as a new assembly into a new `AppDomain`. See for example [**Executing Code in Another Application Domain**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173139(v=vs.100).aspx). I believe this example is close to what you intended.

**Non-cooperative ways**

There are also far more tricky non-cooperative ways, whereby (potentially malicious) code injects itself in the process space of a target application. A summary of some methods that are used to achieve this are listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection):

- You can list a dll under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs` and it will be loaded into every (new) process that links to user32.dll (i.e. pretty much every user-mode process).
- Exploiting a weakness in a function that loads a library by path incorrectly (typically, placing a dll loaded by the target process higher in the search path) or simply replacing an existing library by your own.
- Via [CreateRemoteThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [CreateRemoteThreadEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is a bit more complex (and interesting) but lets you do that for existing processes. An example can be found [here](http://damianblog.com/2008/07/02/net-code-injection/).
- Via [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is the easiest way to do it for a running process.
- Use the SuspendThread or NtSuspendThread function to suspend all threads, and then use SetThreadContext or NtSetContextThread function to modify an existing thread's context in the application to execute injected code.
- Writing a [shim](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2011/06/17/demystifying-shims-or-using-the-app-compat-toolkit-to-make-your-old-stuff-work-with-your-new-stuff.aspx).

It is possible to inject a .NET Assembly into an unmanaged process, as deomnstrated in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607352/Injecting-Net-Assemblies-Into-Unmanaged-Processes), by also loading the .NET runtime into the unmanaged process.

You could also have a look at the [CInject project on Codeplex](http://www.ganshani.com/open-source/cinject-code-injector/), for additional approaches.